# Looking for assistance with auto populating data from a ongoing list

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am attempting to copy the data from a list columns A&B as names and photos and would like it to auto populate horizontally into rows below but only to the 9th column as shown then continue in the following rows beneath the current ones shown in the photo

[image]

[image]

Any help or direction would be gladly appreciated. I have attempted to transpose a list horizontally and have done so with this list but don't know what to do from there or if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I use the formula `IF(ROW()>9,"",OFFSET($A$1,ROW(A1)+(ROUNDUP(COLUMN(A1)/2,0)-1)*9-1,MOD(COLUMN(),2),,)&"")` to get mutliple columns with up to 9 rows data.

But this formula need to be entered in **Row 1 and in even column**, such as D1, F1, H1.

[image]

Then copy the result and choose just keep values, and then copy again, choose Tanspose.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Lastly would you be able to show me how to add a reference at the beginning of this formula to a different sheet still using the list on A/B

Comment: If A/B columns are on Sheet1, the formula results are on Sheet2, you may enter this formula in Row 1 and in even column of Sheet 2, such as D1, `=IF(ROW()>9,"",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROW(Sheet1!A1)+(ROUNDUP(COLUMN(Sheet1!A1)/2,0)-1)*9-1,MOD(COLUMN(),2),,)&"")`

Comment: Thank you Emily, your help is gladly appreciated and I was able to get this to work out well. Take care!